# How does http://qwebirc.org/ work?

Tags: python, chat, push, comet, pull

I think it's a really cool script. But when you're in a chat I'd like to know how it requests new chat content.

I'm interested because the chats I've made in the past have been inefficient and consumed a lot of bandwidth. I tried inspecting element in Chrome and going to Network but it never shows any requests for me. Does it use pull requests, does it use a comet sort of interface? If push, I thought this was a bad idea in PHP because each user's request creates a new PHP process or thread.

Thanks!
Someone Learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download](http://qwebirc.org/download) the code powering the site.
You can also [browse the code](http://hg.qwebirc.org/qwebirc/src)

To answer your question, you should install it, and use firebug to look at network traffic.

**So... you've tagged this as PHP, but you might want to edit it and tag python.**

What do I need to run qwebirc?

You need Python (at least version 2.5) and Twisted (at least version 8.2.0).
On Windows you also require pywin32.
Though qwebirc will work without them, it is highly recommended that you also have Java and Mercurial.
What does qwebirc run on?

The backend should run on anything that supports Python and Twisted, it has been tested on Linux, FreeBSD and Windows (XP and above).
qwebirc is developed for QuakeNet's ircd: snircd; people have reported success on ircu and its derivatives, hyperion, charybdis, ratbox and UltimateIRCd, and in theory it should work on any RFC 1459 compliant ircd.
The frontend is tested on IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 3, Opera 10, Safari and Chrome.
How do I get started?

First make sure you've read the question above and you have everything required installed!
Copy config.py.example to config.py, and edit it to fit your setup.
Run compile.py to generate the HTML, minify the Javascript/CSS and copy everything to the correct locations.
Run run.py (if you get an error about the select reactor being already registered just run it again) -- note run.py has lots of arguments, you can see them with --help.
Browse to http://yourmachine:9090/